# TensorFlow training issue: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train an LSTM network with some sequential data with vehicle trajectories, in order to get driver's intention. Here is how I have structures my data:

- 3 positional features per vehicle, with 5 vehicles for each entry. Each one of this features consists of an array of 50 elements.
- The output of my model would be a classification for each individual vehicle intention, which is coded in 3 intentions (turn left, turn right, keep straight). This way we have 3x5=15 (5 vehicles) output columns. This columns are one hot encoded.

In case this clears it up:

[image: Variable description]

The code I'm trying to execute to build and train my model is the following:

```
input_columns = ['Local_X_0', 'Local_X_dot_0',  'Local_X_ddot_0', 'Local_X_1', 'Local_X_dot_1',  'Local_X_ddot_1', 'Local_X_2', 'Local_X_dot_2',  'Local_X_ddot_2', 
                    'Local_X_3', 'Local_X_dot_3',  'Local_X_ddot_3', 'Local_X_4', 'Local_X_dot_4',  'Local_X_ddot_4']

output_columns = ['Left_Change_0', 'Right_Change_0', 'No_Change_0', 'Left_Change_1', 'Right_Change_1', 'No_Change_1', 'Left_Change_2', 'Right_Change_2', 'No_Change_2',
                    'Left_Change_3', 'Right_Change_3', 'No_Change_3', 'Left_Change_4', 'Right_Change_4', 'No_Change_4']

X = np.array(df_id_arr[input_columns])
Y = np.array(df_id_arr[output_columns])


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

print ('X_train shape: ', X_train.shape)
print ('X_test shape: ', X_test.shape)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(50, 15)),  # Assuming 50 timesteps
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation='softmax')  # 15 output categories
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

But when trying to execute model.fit I get the the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\peroanjo\OneDrive - Universidad Politécnica de Cartagena\Master IA\TFM\Code\LSTM.ipynb Cell 88 in ()
     23 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
     25 # Train the model
---> 26 history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

File c:\Users\peroanjo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\peroanjo\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:102, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

Any idea on what I'm missing? I think I'm not reshaping my input columns correctly, but I can't seem to get it right. Thank you for your help!

I tried reshaping or converting the dataframe column into a numpy array, but this hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, the issue should be related with how data is converted from `Dataframe` to `np.ndarray`. In this case, it appears that `X` has shape `(15499, 15)` but each of the elements is an individual array.

In my small-scale test, it appears that such an incomplete conversion could happen when the shape of the arrays being concatenated are not the same. Consider the following example:

```py
import numpy as np

print(np.array([np.array([3, 5]), np.array([5, 3, 3])]))
# [array([3, 5]) array([5, 3, 3])] plus some warnings

print(np.array([np.array([3, 5, 5]), np.array([5, 3, 3])]))
# [[3 5 5]
# [5 3 3]]
```

So I would double check if there are entries in your data frame with a different number of elements than 50, e.g. if there are empty entries.

Comment: Hi, I tried checking if there are any arrays with a different shape, but it seems like all of them are 50 elements long, any other idea?

Comment: In that case, I would slice out a few rows from the data frame and see, for example, what `np.array(X.head(3)[input_columns])` gives. There it would be easier to directly observe the resulting array. If that's one array with shape `(3, 15, 50)`, there's something in the remaining rows that prevented the same conversion.

Comment: Or maybe try `X = df_id_arr[input_columns].to_numpy()` (see pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)).